# glsl fragmentshader render objectID

Tags: opengl, glsl

How do I properly render an integer ID of an object to an integer texture buffer?

Say I have a texture2D with internal format GL_LUMINANCE16 and i attach it as color attachment to my FBO.

When rendering an object, i pass an integer ID to the shader and would like to render this id into my integer texture.

fragmentshader output is of type vec4 however.
How do I properly transform my ID to four component float and avoid conversion inaccuracies such that in the end the integervalue in my integer texture target corresponds to the integer ID i wanted to render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your question.

First, `GL_LUMINANCE16` is *not* an "integer texture." It is a texture that contains *normalized* unsigned integer values. It uses integers to represent floats on the range [0, 1]. If you want to store actual integers, you must use an actual [integer image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats).

Second, you cannot render to a luminance texture; they are not color-renderable formats. If you actually want to render to a single-channel texture, you must create a single-channel image format. So instead of `GL_LUMINANCE16`, you use `GL_R16UI`, which is a 16-bit single-channel unsigned integral image format.

Now that you have this set up correctly, it's pretty trivial. Define a `uint` fragment shader output and have your fragment shader write your `uint` value to it. This `uint` could come from the vertex shader or from a uniform; however you want to do it.

Obviously you'll also need to attach your texture or renderbuffer to an FBO, but I'm fairly sure you know that.

One final thing: don't use the phrase "texture buffer" unless you mean [one of these](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture). Otherwise, it gets confusing.

Comment: sounds good - though I got it working with GL_LUMINANCE16 already by dividing my ... for some reasons i can render into it - maybe it's just my graphics card that supports it? If I use integral texture format, how can I define int output for only one render target? I use 5 color attachments in my shader, the first 4 render other things int floatingpoint textures, the 5th shall render the objectId. it works now (using GL_LUMINANCE16) but maybe I'm just using undefined behaviour? I have a OpenGL 4.2 context

Comment: @Mat: You have to declare the output to be an `int` to write to `int` outputs. Also, considering that this works, I'm guessing you have an NVIDIA card.

Comment: yes i have an nvidia card. but how can i declare a single output component as int? i have the out variable of my fragmentshader declared as `out vec4 out_colors[5]`

Comment: @Mat: Why did you do that? You can specify each output with a name so that your shader is self-documenting. And then you can use the `layout(location=#)` syntax to associate them with a draw buffer index.

Answer (score 5):

I still don't think that there is a clear answer here. So here is how I made it work through a 2D texture:

```
// First, create a frame buffer:
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

// Then generate your texture and define an unsigned int array:
glGenTextures(1, &textureid);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, w, h, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

// Attach it to the frame buffer object:
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, textureid, 0);

// Before rendering    
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);    
GLuint buffers[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 }; // this assumes that there is another     texture that is for the render buffer. Color attachment1 is preserved for the element ids.
glDrawBuffers(2, buffers);

// Clear and render here
glFlush(); // Flush after just in case
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

On the GLSL side the fragment shader should have (4.3 core profile code here):

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 colorOut; // The first element in 'buffers' so location 0    
layout(location = 1) out uvec4 elementID; // The second element in 'buffers' so location 1. unsigned int vector as color

// ...
void main()
{
//...

elementID = uvec4( elementid, 0, 0, 0 ); // Write the element id as integer to the red channel.

}
```

You can read the values on the host side:

```
unsigned int* ids = new unsigned int[ w*h ];
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ids);
```

Comment: I think accepted answer is a little bit vague. After countless hours, this actually saved my day! Thank you good sir

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your integer ID is an identifier for a set of primitives; indeed it can be defined as an shader uniform:

```
uniform int vertedObjectId;
```

Once you render, you want to store the fragment processing into an [integer texture](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_integer.txt). Note that integer textures shall be sampled with *integer* samplers (`isampler2D`), which returns *integer* vectors (i.e. `ivec3`).

This texture can be attached to a framebuffer object (be aware of [framebuffer completeness](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness)). The framebuffer attachment can be [bound](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glBindFragDataLocation.xml) to an integer output variable:

```
out int fragmentObjectId;

void main() {
    fragmentObjectId = vertedObjectId;
}
```

You need a few extension supports, or an advanced OpenGL version (3.2?).